# Spring boot 2 oAuth2 - There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I'm setting up a REST API server which should work only with client_credentials flow, so I have no users but only clients to access my resources.

I'm using SPRING BOOT PARENT 2.0.2.RELEASE and Spring Security Oauth2 2.3.4.RELEASE

When trying to get the token i keep receiving this error:

```
There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.
```

This is how i configure my AuthServer

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(
      AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) 
      throws Exception {
        oauthServer
        .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
          .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
          .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) 
      throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
          .withClient("client")
          .secret("{noop}secret")
          .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "client_credentials")
          .scopes("read", "write");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(
      AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) 
      throws Exception {

        endpoints
          .tokenStore(tokenStore())
          .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
          .setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService)

    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
}
```

This is how i set the general Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

@Order(-1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable();

    }

      @Bean
             @Override
             public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
                     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
           }

}
```

and finally the ResourceServer (which should not be important in this issue)

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConf extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api*")
        .authenticated();

    }

}
```

I try to get the token with a POST call to /oauth/token in this way `oauth/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=client_credentials`

What do i miss?